# Is there any way to see tmpfs devices mounted under WSL2/Ubuntu2004 from Windows?

Tags: networking, mount, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmpfs

I'm trying to run some tests against a large number of small-medium (<10KB) files.  Everything is going fine, but now I'm at the point where I want to see what I can do with msys2 and github tools against those tmpfs mounts.  Unfortunately I don't see any contents when I navigate to those locations over the local network share:

[image: Windows10 screenshot of /mnt on Ubuntu 20.04]

[image: Windows10 screenshot of /mnt/ramdisktest 'this folder is empty']

From within WSL2/Ubuntu, however, you can see that the contents of the tmpfs are not empty:

```
_☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠_
| mattg@MSI:/mnt
|☣> cd ramdisktest/
_☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠_
| mattg@MSI:/mnt/ramdisktest
|☣> ll
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 mattg 143 Feb 18 19:13 testfile
_☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠_
| mattg@MSI:/mnt/ramdisktest
|☣> pwd
/mnt/ramdisktest
_☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠_
| mattg@MSI:/mnt/ramdisktest
|☣> cat testfile
/home
/srv
/etc
/opt
/root
/lib
/mnt
/usr
/media
/lib64
/sys
/dev
/sbin
/boot
/bin
/run
/lib32
/libx32
/init
/proc
/snap
/tmp
/var
/lost+found
_☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠__☠_
| mattg@MSI:/mnt/ramdisktest
|☣>
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a permissions problem?  I just did a tmpfs mount under WSL and I can see the files from Explorer using the `\\wsl$\<distro>` path.  What about `/run`?  That's a tmpfs that is mounted by the `/init`.  Can you see the files in there from Windows?  If so, compare the mount options and permissions.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I tried using options UID=1000 and GID too but nothing changed.  I can't find any combination that changes anything in windows.  The other options on the tmpfs files you mentioned aren't allowed for ramdisk mounts.  I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Still noodling on this (as I'm sure you are as well).  What's `grep ramdisktest /etc/mtab` show?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds `tmpfs /mnt/ramdisktest tmpfs rw,relatime,size=102400k,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`